# How to implement FBA in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, forms-authentication

What is the best way to implement FBA in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly what you want FBA with SQL or LDAP. ANy who.

[Configuring SharePoint 2013 Forms-Based Authentication with SQLMemberShipProvider](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider.aspx)

or LDAP

[Configure forms-based authentication for a claims-based web application in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806890%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Here are good Youtube Video for this.

[Implementing and Configuring FBA in SharePoint 2013 - Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsAddue2S7s)
[Implementing and Configuring FBA in SharePoint 2013 - Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zO050Xw7vnc)

Answer (score 1):

If SQL Authentication is intended, the most easiest is to take this Codeplex project to start with:

[SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack](http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/)